# Defined variable in outer scope is not defined in inner scope

Tags: javascript, scope, ecmascript-6

The following code throws a ReferenceError 'a is not defined'.

```
{
    let a = 'a1';
    {
        console.log(a);
        let a = 'a2';
    }
}
```

As do the next one.

```
{
    const a = 'a1';
    {
        console.log(a);
        const a = 'a2';
    }
}
```

If you instead use var declarations it works as I expect it to. (No error error thrown and 'a1' logged.)

It gets even harder for me to comprehend when I try to analyze the following code.

```
{
    let a = 'a1';
    {
        console.log(a);
        var a = 'a2';
    }
}
```

It throws a SyntaxError, "Identifier 'a' has already been declared".

Naïvely I expected an identifier to be shadowed *not until after* a let or const declaration, like the behavior of let in Clojure or let* in Racket. As [described clearly on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let), this is not how it works.

But *why* does it work this way? Why does Racket have both a let and a let* form?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it does not answer my question. I understand _how_ it works, but not _why_ this model is chosen. Is it because of performance issues?

Comment: SO is not a place to ask _why_ a language has a particular feature or behavior. Ask [TC-39](https://www.ecma-international.org/memento/TC39-RF-TG.htm), they know without speculations. I could speculate a bit. Maybe the hoisting mechanism was found so important, that it was preferred over the outer scope variables?

Comment: @JohanJonasson Why it was chosen? Because scopes in ES6 are always block/function-body based, `let` does not introduce a new scope. This for example does allow mutually recursive declarations without extra hazzle. Also it's less error-prone not to have `a` available at all when you wouldn't be sure which variable it does refer to.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, that's an interesting answer. If I understand you correctly, every let/const declaration would have to introduce a new scope if they should behave the way I expected?

Comment: Yes. If you rewrite your example to Clojure, the scopes become explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by hoisting the internal `let` or `const` to the top of the block ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Temporal_dead_zone_and_errors_with_let)), and create a **Temporal Dead Zone**.

> In ECMAScript 2015, let will hoist the variable to the top of the
>   block. However, referencing the variable in the block before the
>   variable declaration results in a ReferenceError. The variable is in a
>   "temporal dead zone" from the start of the block until the declaration
>   is processed.

The reason behind this is simple - silent failing vs throwing error.

In this example, a similar setting is giving the result as `undefined` because of the `var` hoisting. This is a silent error, and it might be very hard to debug.

```js
{
    var a = 'a1';
    (function() {
        console.log(a);
        var a = 'a2';
    })();
}
```

If you'll use `let` or `const` an error will be thrown:

```js
{
  let a = 'a1';
  (function() {
    console.log(a);
    let a = 'a2';
  })();
}
```

You can find more info about the **temporal dead zone** in the article [TEMPORAL DEAD ZONE (TDZ) DEMYSTIFIED](http://jsrocks.org/2015/01/temporal-dead-zone-tdz-demystified/).